# MySQL поиск по ключевым словам в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, просьба помочь.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что в php через foreach крайне долго анализировать посты по ключевым словам. Подумал я, что через БД можно как-то оптимизировать этот процесс. Так ли это?
Ключевые слова у меня лежат в таблице keyword, таблица keyword имеет структуру: 
id(int), text(text), category(int)
Всего ключевых слов порядка 40.
Посты лежат в одноименной таблице posts, таблица имеет структуру:
id(int), text(text), date(timestamp), status(int) и т.д.
Главный вопрос, который стоит передо мной - это как постоянно мапить все посты (предположим, их ежедневно штук 30-40) проверяя каждый элемент posts.text на наличие совпадения по первому вхождению keyword.text?

Объясню на примере: если у нас условно есть посты, которые содержат:
[image: скриншот]

Comment: `left join + like` или что? зы: у вас текст постав ведь вряд ли меняется, почему бы не сохранять категорию в таблицу при добавлении поста или слова?

Comment: @teran текст парсится, а при парсинге на уровне php тоже боль проверять по всем ключевым словам.

Comment: в целом не знаю, где там у вас боль, но если не хочется делать в php можно сделать в триггере вставки. Но суть сейчас не в этом. замечание было о том, что с ростом объема таблиц like начнет тормозить, и если текст постов не изменяются, делать это динамически смысла нет.

Comment: С "первым" вхождением возникнут большие трудности. like не дает позицию совпадения в строке. а это значит что строку надо будет сначала разбить на слова, а потом эти слова уже матчить с ключевыми словами. Вот если бы задача была найти все вхождения то select с join по условию like все бы нашел.

Comment: @Mike вот об это я что-то не подумал. P.S. Пока что написал цикл получения всех ключевых слова и собрал большой запрос с WHERE AND LIKE, где смотрю только те записи, которым не присвоена категория (определяю по значению 0). Осталось только заджойнить ID категории, далее update. В принципе отработка за 0,0021 - намного приятнее, чем отработка полностью пышной проверки за секунды. Но пока не знаю, что делать с LIKE, т.к. хотелось бы искать построчно.

Comment: Хотя если вместо like использовать REGEXP_INSTR и записать ключевые слова в виде регулярных выражений, то задача становится проще. Ищем все совпадения, оставляем с минимальной позицией. как именно оставлять первое зависит от версии mysql

Comment: я чет подумал что "первое вхождение" это трудности формулировки мыслей ) В качестве категории для постов нужно проставить ту, где ключевое слово встречается ближе к началу текста? то есть для текста `xxx major cs:go` это будет 4 а для `xxx cs:go major` соответственно 8?

Comment: @teran да, именно так)
Пока что дошел до решения "быдлокодер". Что я сделал: 1) Получаю ключевые слова 2) В цикле собираю массивы вида "`text` LIKE $text" (где $text - это ключевое слово) 3) Превращаю все полученное в цикле в строку 4) Через SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status = 0 AND (`text` LIKE "$text_foreach_1" or `text` LIKE "$text_foreach_2" и т.д.) получаю нужный мне массив.

Comment: Осталось понять, как в полученный запрос правильно вставить category ключевых слов, превратив их в категории для постов.

Comment: если у вас шаблоны бывают вида `xxx%` или `%xxx` но не бывают `xx%yy` то может через locate вообще сделать.

Comment: и LIKE и REGEXP будут сильно тормозить при росте таблиц. тут уже писали выше про это (teran). Если у вас порядка десятков ключевых слов (сейчас писали, что 40), то почему не забирать их в кэш и не обновлять его при редактировании? Далее получается (предположительно), что добавление / редактирование любого поста сводится к прогону на наличие ключевых слов и обновлению списка категорий этого поста. Не очень понимаю, где тут "боль" без кода

Comment: @Дмитрий объясню. Если мы парсим один источник - проблем нет и на php через циклы искать в тексте ключевые слова, т.к. кол-во постов будет маленькое. Но, что делать, если источники увеличатся, а следовательно и постов будет не 40, а предположим 4000. Через php у меня это займет ~210 сек. Я думал (и думаю), что через БД это будет быстрее.

Comment: видимо я не понимаю источник постов. Если пост вводится / редактируется пользователем и сохраняется, то у вас явно есть валидация и сохранение и привязку можно делать где-то здесь. Собственно ~40 ключевых слов вполне в регулярное выражение влезают и анализируются на порядок вхождения (ну или не до конца понимаю задачу). Если же вы откуда-то парсите / получаете или пакеты уже готовых постов, то вы вполне можете организовать очередь их обработки. В общем - явно не хватает вводных данных для понимания. Но в целом, на мой взгляд, базка всегда менее масштабируема, чем PHP-приложение

Comment: @Дмитрий - нет, в том то и дело. Пост не вводится вручную, а парсится. К примеру: у сайтов есть XML, я их парсю (у каждого сайта своя структура, следовательно у каждого своя функция для парсинга xml), который сводится к одному формату, а далее в нужном мне формате сохраняется в БД через многострочный инсерт.

Comment: хех, останусь при своем мнении, что через базу плохо. А такой вопрос: если у вас категория определяется однозначно (один пост - одна категория) по тому, какое из ключевых слов ближе к началу поста (или NULL, если не нашли), почему не зайдет механизм через регулярные выражения?

Comment: Например у нас есть текст из моего комментария; "видимо я не понимаю...". Пропускаем его через if (preg_match("/^(.*?)(источник|ключевых слов|базка|PHP)/umi", $text, $keywd)). Тут  (источник|ключевых слов|базка|PHP) - перечисление ключевых слов. Если успех, то в $keywd[2] лежит как раз первое встретившееся ключевое слово. Иначе - ни одного не нашли.

Comment: просто с ростом базы все варианты с LIKE будет деградировать время работы.

Comment: @Дмитрий я пару дней поразмышлял над Вашими словами и пришел к выводу, что все же вы правы, и действительно стоит оставить реализацию на PHP) По итогу решено подправить циклы foreach, уменьшить их кол-во, дабы иметь всего 3 цикла. В первом (for) хочу получать массивы (с ним возникли трудности), во втором тэги перевожу в строку, а третий цикл вложен во второй, где я как раз через preg_match ищу совпадения по регуляркам. Через LIKE/FULLTEXT при большой БД есть вероятность усугубить положение, но насколько - узнал только погуглив.

Comment: А можно код? Что-то не понятное и с первым циклом и трудностями с массивами, и что вы делаете в третьем цикле с регулярными выражениями? Вроде бы я думал вам нужно найти одно, самое первое, вхождение любого из ключевых слов в посте и по нему задать категорию.

Comment: @Дмитрий я для этого вопроса новую ветку создал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1501646/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d1%8b